# OR(|), XOR(^), AND(&) overloading

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading, bitwise-operators

How do I overload the &, | and ^ operators in C# and how does overloading work?

I have been trying to find some good answers for some time but have not found any. I will share any helpful articles.

Comment: what exactly is your question ? just examples ? or a howto ? or whether it is possible ?

Comment: @Yahia Thank you for your reply sir. 
I would basically like to know how to use them.
I am sorry if my question was not appropriate.

Comment: I've reworked the question to make it clearer and be an answerable question.

Comment: @Jeff Yates Thank you for your correction. I shall frame the question better the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By implementing operators for your classes in C#, you are not actually *overloading* operators. You are simply implementing them for the first time. They are methods, just like any other, but with special syntax. Instead of calling `c = Add(a, b)` you call `c = a + b`, where `+` is an operator (method) that returns a value.

By implementing the following methods, the `&=` `|=`, and `^=` methods have been automatically implemented.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass operator &(MyClass left, MyClass right)
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }

    public static MyClass operator |(MyClass left, MyClass right)
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }

    public static MyClass operator ^(MyClass left, MyClass right)
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}

var a = new MyClass();
var b = new MyClass();

var c = a & b;
var d = a | b;
var e = a ^ b;

a &= b; // a = a & b;
c |= d; // c = c & d;
e ^= e; // e = e ^ e;
```

*Overloading* is performed at compile time. It ensures that a specific method is called based on the method's name and parameter type and count.

*Overiding* is performed at runtime. It allows a subclass's method to be called instead of the parent method, even when the instance was being treated as the parent class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

So I would be overloading when I mention the following             

`public static MyClass operator &(MyClass left, MyClass right)
 {
        return new MyClass();
 }

 public static MyClass operator &(MyClass left, bool right)
 {
        return new MyClass();
 }
 public static MyClass operator &(bool left, MyClass right)
 {
        return new MyClass();
 }
`

Comment: Exactly. That would be overloading. If you created a `class SubMyClass : MyClass { }` and made new operator implementations, you still wouldn't be using *overriding*, because you would need make the base class' operators `virtual`. Then you would need to `override` them in the sub class.

Comment: Just make sure you use operators for their intended purpose (adding, dividing, multiplying, xor-ing, etc). Don't make "creative" use of operators, unless you intend to make a crazy delicious DSL. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. From the above conversation I understand that, using operators wisely is very critical to it's actual purpose.

Answer (score 3):

For some articles/tutorials/references on operator overloading including binary/bitwise operators and sample source code see:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/introtooperatoroverloads.aspx
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/operator
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

As for "how to use them" the basic rule is that overloaded operators should make sense in the domain you implement them...

For example you could build a genetic/evolutionary algorithm and define some/all of the bitwise/binary operators in a way consistent with the "recombination/mutation" step (i.e. creating the next generation from current population) of that algorithm - this would make for rather elegant code in that specific context.

Comment: Thank you for the sources you have provided. I went through them and they were useful. Looking forward to your posts.

Answer (score 0):

How to use them? Carefully.
They need to make sense.
E.g. Defining say a Type to hold a ComplexNumber or a Matrix and then overloading arithmetical operators makes sense.

Don't go down the foolish route of overloading an operator because you don't like typing.

e.g. MyThingyList + SomeFileName loads MyThingyList from the file.

or

MyThingyList-- calls MyThingsList.Clear().

Comment: Thanks Tony. I shall be very judicious about using the operator. Looking forward to your posts.