# VB.Net Power operator (^) overloading from C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I am writing a C# class that is exposed to VB.Net. I would like to overload the vb.net `^` operator so that I can write:

```
Dim c as MyClass
Set c = New ...
Dim d as MyClass
Set d = c^2
```

In C#, the `^` operator is the `xor` operator and the power operator doesn't exist. Is there a way I can do this anyway?

Comment: Not sure if this works in vb.net from a C# lib, but here's a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069665/or-xor-and-overloading

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT**

It turns out there's a `SpecialNameAttribute` that lets you declare "special" functions in C# that will allow you (among other things) to overload the VB power operator:

```
public class ExponentClass
{
    public double Value { get; set; }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.SpecialName]
    public static ExponentClass op_Exponent(ExponentClass o1, ExponentClass o2)
    {
        return new ExponentClass { Value = Math.Pow(o1.Value, o2.Value) };
    }
}
```

The `op_Exponent` function in the class above gets translated by VB into the `^` power operator.

Interestingly, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.specialnameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states the Attribute in not currently used by the .NET framework...

--ORIGINAL ANSWER  --

No.  The power (`^`) operator gets compiled as `Math.Pow()` so there's no way to "overload" it in C#.

From LinqPad:

```
Sub Main
    Dim i as Integer
    Dim j as Integer
    j = Integer.Parse("6")
    i = (5^j)
    i.Dump()
End Sub
```

IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       "6"
IL_0006:  call        System.Int32.Parse
IL_000B:  stloc.1     
IL_000C:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 14 40 
IL_0015:  ldloc.1     
IL_0016:  conv.r8     
IL_0017:  call        System.Math.Pow
IL_001C:  call        System.Math.Round
IL_0021:  conv.ovf.i4 
IL_0022:  stloc.0     
IL_0023:  ldloc.0     
IL_0024:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump
```

Comment: +1. That's what I expected. Just could not find a proof link.

Comment: Mmmh, but VB.Net allows for the ^ operator overloading, and that compiles into a dll that can be loaded somewhere else. So the ^ operator overloading must be some valid IL. The question is, can this IL be generated from C#...

Comment: @d--b: following same principle, it probably gets compiled to call whatever your implementation is, rather than storing it as an operator override.

Comment: @Neolisk: but how could the compiler know what to do? If I create a class say `Matrix` in VB.Net with an overload on ^ and put it in a dll (Matrix.dll). How will the compiler know **just by loading the dll** that the operator has been overloaded on that class?

Comment: @d--b: I just tried - it appears that `^` operator gets translated into `op_Exponent` function, so this is what's available to you from C#.

Comment: The overload gets compiled to a static `op_Exponent` function that is callable by that name from C#.  I have yet to find a way to recreate this operator from C# such that it will be recognized by VB.

Comment: @d--b I have found the secret attribute that allows you to overload the operator.  See my edited answer.

Comment: @DStanley: Amazing! Can I somehow give you another upvote for finding that?

Comment: Interestingly enough, even though F# emits the name `op_Exponentiation` for the exponentiation operator (`**`), this trick doesn't work for F#. Instead, F# looks for a static method named `Pow`. What a mess.

Answer (score 2):

By experiment, it turns out that operator overloading is just syntactic sugar, and better be avoided, if you need to develop in multiple languages. For example, `^` operator of VB.NET gets translated into `op_Exponent` function, so this is what's available to you from C#.

[Why doesn't C# have a power operator?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-have-a-power-operator.aspx)

You can use a native .NET way so you don't rely on operators:

```
Math.Pow(x, y);
```

Also for y=2 it is faster to use multiplication (x*x).

Comment: @Joey: could you please elaborate on how you would replace power with addition, and make it faster than multiplication? Not quite apparent to me.

Comment: Ah, nevermind; I was thinking of 2 ⋅ *x* being often slower than *x* + *x*. Had my mind mixed up for a moment there.

Comment: @Joey: no problem, and thanks for pointing at a typo in my answer - now fixed.