# Purpose and Meaning of "specialname" and "rtspecialname" in IL

Tags: c#, il, ildasm

I am trying to understand the IL code and C# internals specifically nowadays, i wrote a simple c# hello world program whose code is :

```
using System;
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and here is IL generated  for the constuctor of `Program` class :

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  ret
} // end of method Program::.ctor
```

I am not able to understand what is the meaning and purpose of *specialname* and *rtspecialname* or what's the use of them ?

Comment: it is not helping me , may be it is related to this, but i am looking for a clear and detailed answer for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the [ECMA 335 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf):

> **rtspecialname** indicates that the name of this item has special significance to the CLI. There are no currently defined special type names; this is for future use. Any item marked **rtspecialname** shall also
> be marked **specialname**.

> **specialname** indicates that the name of this item can have special significance to tools other than the CLI. See, for example, Partition I .

These attributes are used either by tools or the runtime to determine if an attribute or method has a special use or significance - one example ([What other neat tricks does the SpecialNameAttribute allow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260695/what-other-neat-tricks-does-the-specialnameattribute-allow)) is to mark an operator to prevent collisions with the user namespace.  Another one I see in the standard is for getters and setters of properties, and it appears that the `Main` method you cited is another example.

---

Although I marked the original question as a duplicate, this question is slightly different in scope and the answer here might shed some more light.  I hope anyway.

Comment: In case anyone else is as dense as I seem to be, rt = "runtime."