# Different IL generated when adding one more int variable

Tags: c#, il, csc, ildasm

I have this program in c#:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 12.34;
    double PI = Math.PI;
    string name = "Ehsan";


    }
}
```

and when i compile it, following is the IL generated by compiler for Main:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       30 (0x1e)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (int32 V_0,
           float64 V_1,
           float64 V_2,
           string V_3)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldc.r8     12.34
  IL_000c:  stloc.1
  IL_000d:  ldc.r8     3.1415926535897931
  IL_0016:  stloc.2
  IL_0017:  ldstr      "Ehsan"
  IL_001c:  stloc.3
  IL_001d:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

which is fine and i understand it, now if i add another integer variable then something different is generated, here is the modified c# code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    int unassigned;
    int i = 4;
    unassigned = i;
    double d = 12.34;
        double PI = Math.PI;
    string name = "Ehsan";


    }
}
```

and here is the IL generated against the above c# code:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       33 (0x21)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (int32 V_0,
           int32 V_1,
           float64 V_2,
           float64 V_3,
           string V_4)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_0002:  stloc.1
  IL_0003:  ldloc.1
  IL_0004:  stloc.0
  IL_0005:  ldc.r8     12.34
  IL_000e:  stloc.2
  IL_000f:  ldc.r8     3.1415926535897931
  IL_0018:  stloc.3
  IL_0019:  ldstr      "Ehsan"
  IL_001e:  stloc.s    V_4  // what is happening here in this case
  IL_0020:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

If you note now the `stloc.s` statement is generated with `V_4` which is local but i am not clear about this and i am also not getting what is the purpose of these locals here, i mean these:

```
 .locals init (int32 V_0,
               float64 V_1,
               float64 V_2,
               string V_3)
```

Comment: There is no `stloc.4`, so you have to use `stloc.s local_variable_reference` instead. *i am also not getting what is the purpose of these locals here* It is your local variables `int i; double d; double PI; string name;`.

Comment: what you mean by there is no ``stloc.4`` ?

Comment: There are four `stloc` shortcuts `stloc.0`, `stloc.1`, `stloc.2` and `stloc.3`. To address local variable with index 4 or greater you have to use `stloc.s` or `stloc`.

Comment: how to use ``stloc`` in index greater than 4 case

Comment: `stloc.s index` or `stloc.s local_variable_name` or `stloc index` or `stloc local_variable_name`.

Comment: For starters, you are looking at debug IL. Make sure C# compiler is set to optimize with no debug. `stloc` `ldloc` is a dead give away. They need that for debugging :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some things to note.

First, this is presumably a debug build, or at least has certain optimisations turned off in the compilation. What I would expect to see here is:

```
.method public hidebysig static void Main () cil managed 
{
  .entrypoint

  IL_0000: ret
}
```

Which is to say, since those locals aren't used, I'd expect the compiler to just skip them entirely. It won't on a debug build, but this stands as a good example of how there can be considerable difference between what the C# says and what the IL says.

The next thing to note is how an IL method is structured. You have an array of local values, which is defined with the `.locals` block, of various types. These will generally correspond pretty closely to what the C# had, though there'll often be short-cuts and re-arrangements made.

Finally we have the set of instructions which all act upon those locals, any arguments, and a stack to which it can push, from which it can pop, and upon which various instructions will interact.

The next thing to note is that the IL you see here is a sort of assembly for byte-code: Every instruction here has a one-to-one mapping to one or two bytes, and every value also consumes a certain number of bytes. So for example, `stloc V_4` (not actually present in your examples, but we'll come to that) would map to `0xFE 0x0E 0x04 0x00` where `0xFE 0x0E` is the encoding of `stloc` and `0x04 0x00` that of `4` which is the index of the local in question. It means "pop the value of the top of the stack, and store it in the 5th (index 4) local".

Now, there are a few abbreviations here. One of these is the `.s` "short" form of several instructions (`_S` in the name of the equivalent `System.Reflection.Emit.OpCode` value). These are variants of other instructions that take a one-byte value (signed or unsigned depending on the instruction) where the other form takes a two- or four-byte value, generally indices or relative distances to jump. So instead of `stloc V_4` we can have `stloc.s V_4` which is only `0x13 0x4`, and so is smaller.

Then there are some variants that include a particular value in the instruction. So instead of either `stloc V_0` or `stloc.s V_0` we can just use `stloc.0` which is just the single byte `0x0A`.

This makes a lot of sense when you consider that it's common to only have a handful of locals in use at a time, so using either `stloc.s` or (better yet) the likes of `stloc.0`, `stloc.1`, etc.) gives tiny savings that add up to quite a lot.

But only so much. If we had e.g `stloc.252`, `stloc.253` etc. then there'd be a lot of such instructions, and the number of bytes needed for each instruction would have to be more, and it would overall be a loss. The super-short forms of the local-related (`stloc`, `ldloc`) and argument-related (`ldarg`) only go up to `3`. (There is a `starg` and `starg.s` but no `starg.0` etc. as storing to arguments is relatively rare). `ldc.i4`/`ldc.i4.s` (push a constant 32-bit signed value onto the stack) has super-short versions going from `ldc.i4.0` to `ldc.i4.8` and also `lcd.i4.m1` for `-1`.

It's also worth noting that the `V_4` doesn't exist in your code at all. Whatever you examined the IL with didn't know you'd used the variable-name `name` so it just used `V_4`. (What are you using, BTW? I use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) for the most part, and if you'd debug information associated with the file it would have called it `name` accordingly).

So, to produce a commented non-shorted version of your method with more comparable names we could write the following CIL:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (int32 unassigned,
           int32 i,
           float64 d,
           float64 PI,
           string name)
  nop                           // Do Nothing (helps debugger to have some of these around).
  ldc.i4   4                    // Push number 4 on stack
  stloc    i                    // Pop value from stack, put in i (i = 4)
  ldloc    i                    // Push value in i on stack
  stloc    unassigned           // Pop value from stack, put in unassigned (unassigned = i)
  ldc.r8   12.34                // Push the 64-bit floating value 12.34 onto the stack
  stloc    d                    // Push the value on stack in d (d = 12.34)
  ldc.r8   3.1415926535897931   // Push the 64-bit floating value 3.1415926535897931 onto the stack.
  stloc PI                      // Pop the value from stack, put in PI (PI = 3.1415… which is the constant Math.PI)
  ldstr    "Ehsan"              // Push the string "Ehsan" on stack
  stloc    name                 // Pop the value from stack, put in name
  ret                           // return.
}
```

That will behave pretty much as your code does, but be a bit larger. So we replace the `stloc` with `stloc.0`…`stloc.3` where we can, `stloc.s` where we can't use those but can still use `stloc.s`, and `ldc.i4 4` with `ldc.i4.4`, and we'll have shorter bytecode that does the same thing:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (int32 unassigned,
           int32 i,
           float64 d,
           float64 PI,
           string name)
  nop                           // Do Nothing (helps debugger to have some of these around).
  ldc.i4.4                      // Push number 4 on stack
  stloc.1                       // Pop value from stack, put in i (i = 4)
  ldloc.1                       // Push value in i on stack
  stloc.0                       // Pop value from stack, put in unassigned (unassigned = i)
  ldc.r8   12.34                // Push the 64-bit floating value 12.34 onto the stack
  stloc.2                       // Push the value on stack in d (d = 12.34)
  ldc.r8   3.1415926535897931   // Push the 64-bit floating value 3.1415926535897931 onto the stack.
  stloc.3                       // Pop the value from stack, put in PI (PI = 3.1415… which is the constant Math.PI)
  ldstr    "Ehsan"              // Push the string "Ehsan" on stack
  stloc.s  name                 // Pop the value from stack, put in name
  ret                           // return.
}
```

And now we've exactly the same code that your disassembly had, except that we've got better names. Remember, the names don't appear in the byte code, so the disassembler couldn't do as good a job as we can.

---

Your question in a comment should really be another question, but it offers a chance to add something important that I only briefly noted above. Let's consider:

```
public static void Maybe(int a, int b)
{
  if (a > b)
    Console.WriteLine("Greater");
  Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Compile in debug and you end up with something like:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
  void Maybe (
    int32 a,
    int32 b
  ) cil managed 
{
  .maxstack 2
  .locals init (
    [0] bool CS$4$0000
  )

  IL_0000: nop
  IL_0001: ldarg.0
  IL_0002: ldarg.1
  IL_0003: cgt
  IL_0005: ldc.i4.0
  IL_0006: ceq
  IL_0008: stloc.0
  IL_0009: ldloc.0
  IL_000a: brtrue.s IL_0017

  IL_000c: ldstr "Greater"
  IL_0011: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0016: nop

  IL_0017: ldstr "Done"
  IL_001c: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0021: nop
  IL_0022: ret
}
```

Now one thing to note is that all of the labels like `IL_0017` etc. are added to every line based on the index of the instruction. This makes life easier for the disassembler, but isn't really necessary unless a label is jumped to. Let's strip out all labels that aren't jumped to:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
  void Maybe (
    int32 a,
    int32 b
  ) cil managed 
{
  .maxstack 2
  .locals init (
    [0] bool CS$4$0000
  )

  nop
  ldarg.0
  ldarg.1
  cgt
  ldc.i4.0
  ceq
  stloc.0
  ldloc.0
  brtrue.s IL_0017

  ldstr "Greater"
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  nop

  IL_0017: ldstr "Done"
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  nop
  ret
}
```

Now, let's consider what each line does:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
  void Maybe (
    int32 a,
    int32 b
  ) cil managed 
{
  .maxstack 2
  .locals init (
    [0] bool CS$4$0000
  )

  nop                   // Do nothing
  ldarg.0               // Load first argument (index 0) onto stack.
  ldarg.1               // Load second argument (index 1) onto stack.
  cgt                   // Pop two values from stack, push 1 (true) if the first is greater
                        // than the second, 0 (false) otherwise.
  ldc.i4.0              // Push 0 onto stack.
  ceq                   // Pop two values from stack, push 1 (true) if the two are equal,
                        // 0 (false) otherwise.
  stloc.0               // Pop value from stack, store in first local (index 0)
  ldloc.0               // Load first local onto stack.
  brtrue.s IL_0017      // Pop value from stack. If it's non-zero (true) jump to IL_0017

  ldstr "Greater"       // Load string "Greater" onto stack.

                        // Call Console.WriteLine(string)
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  nop                   // Do nothing

  IL_0017: ldstr "Done" // Load string "Done" onto stack.
                        // Call Console.WriteLine(string)
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  nop                   // Do nothing
  ret                   // return
}
```

Let's write this back into C# in a very literal step-by step way:

```
public static void Maybe(int a, int b)
{
  bool shouldJump = (a > b) == false;
  if (shouldJump) goto IL_0017;
  Console.WriteLine("Greater");
IL_0017:
  Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Try that and you'll see it does the same thing. The use of `goto` is because CIL doesn't really have anything like `for` or `while` or even blocks we can put after an `if` or `else`, it just has jumps and conditional jumps.

But why does it bother to store the value (what I called `shouldJump` in my C# rewrite) rather than just act on it?

It's just to make it easier to examine what is going on at each point if you are debugging. In particular, for a debugger to be able to stop at the point where `a > b` is worked out but not yet acted on then either `a > b` or its opposite (`a <= b`) needs to be stored.

Debug builds tend to write CIL that spends a lot of time writing a record of what it just did, for that reason. With a release build we'd get something more like:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
  void Maybe (
    int32 a,
    int32 b
  ) cil managed 
{
  ldarg.0           // Load first argument onto stack
  ldarg.1           // Load second argument onto stack
  ble.s IL_000e     // Pop two values from stack. If the first is
                    // less than or equal to the second, goto IL_000e: 
  ldstr "Greater"   // Load string "Greater" onto stack.
                    // Call Console.WriteLine(string)
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
                    // Load string "Done" onto stack.
  IL_000e: ldstr "Done"
                    // Call Console.WriteLine(string)
  call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  ret
}
```

Or to do a similar line-by-line write back into C#:

```
public static void Maybe(int a, int b)
{
  if (a <= b) goto IL_000e;
  Console.WriteLine("Greater");
IL_000e:
  Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

So you can see how the release build is more concisely doing the same thing.

Comment: Don't ask if you can ask a question. Ask the question.

Comment: can you explain me this IL, it is comparison ``if(a > b)`` in IL can you explain with comments as you did in your answer : ``IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldarg.1
  IL_0003:  cgt
  IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0006:  ceq
  IL_0008:  stloc.0
  IL_0009:  ldloc.0
  IL_000a:  brtrue.s   IL_0019``

Comment: I am actually not able to get how this comaprison working suppose a is greater than b here

Comment: Actually. Wait a minute.

Comment: There. Hopefully that explains a bit.

Comment: can you answer this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026958/purpose-and-meaning-of-specialname-and-rtspecialname-in-il

Answer (score 5):

MSIL is heavily micro-optimized to make the storage as small as possible.  Turn to the [Opcodes class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and note the listed `Stloc` instructions.  There are 6 versions of it, they all do the exact same thing.

`Stloc_0`, `Stloc_1`, `Stloc_2` and `Stloc_3` are the minimal ones, they only take a single byte.  The variable number they use is implicit, 0 through 3.  Very commonly used of course.

Then there's `Stloc_S`, it is a two-byte opcode, the second byte to encode the variable number.  This one needs to be used when a method has more than 4 variables.

Finally there's `Stloc`, it is a three-byte opcode, using two bytes to encode the variable number.  Must be used when a method has more than 256 variables.  Hopefully you'll never do that.  You are out of luck when you write a monster that has more than 65536 variables, that is not supported.  Has been done btw, auto-generated code can blow past this limit.

So easy to see what happened in the second snippet, you added the `unassigned` variable and increased the number of local variables from 4 to 5.  Since there is no `Stloc_4`, the compiler *must* use `Stloc_S` to assign the 5th variable.

Comment: any thoughts on this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026958/purpose-and-meaning-of-specialname-and-rtspecialname-in-il

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have anything to do with your question.  Just follow the link the first comment to see my thoughts.